Formula with Inverse Fourier Transform
Let $a>0$ and consider a Schwartz function $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and define the Fourier transform as $$
\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ix\xi}f(x)dx \quad \hbox{ and } \quad \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi}f(\xi)d\xi.
$$
I have to show that there is a constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
c \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a}{\xi^2+a^2} e^{ix\xi}f(\xi) d\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a|x-t|} \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(t) dt
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
my try: I started from the RHS replacing $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)(x)$ by the definition and continued to substitute
$x-t=u$. I got
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-au-i\xi u} e^{ix\xi}f(\xi) d\xi du $$
but now I'm stuck to derive the LHS. Any hints/suggestions?

You had the correct idea.  Since $f\in \mathbb{S}$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a|x-t|}\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{f\}(t)\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a|x-t|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi)e^{i\xi t}\,d\xi\,dt\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{Fubini}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a|x-t|}e^{i\xi t}\,dt\,d\xi\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{u=x-t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi)e^{i\xi x} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a|u|}e^{-i\xi u}\,du\,d\xi\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi)e^{i\xi x} \left(\frac{2a}{a^2+\xi^2}\right)\,d\xi
\end{align}$$
Thus, we find that for $c=2$, we have
$$c\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{a}{a^2+\xi^2} f(\xi)e^{i\xi x} \,d\xi=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a|x-t|}\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{f\}(t)\,dt$$
And we are done!

Ah, I overlooked that the inner integral can be calculated, thanks for your help!

You're welcome.   My pleasure.
